# Installing Ubuntu mate via XFCE on a chromebook

Tags: apt, xfce, mate, chromebook

I'm following this guide: https://medium.com/power-user/ubuntu-mate-on-a-chromebook-with-crouton-2cebd167382#.bjbns1p7v

I've gotten to the part where I'm trying to retrieve and install ubuntu mate.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

However I get the following error msg:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-mate-core : Depends: mate-desktop-environment-core but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ubuntu-mate-default-settings but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-mate-desktop : Depends: mate-menu but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: mozo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've `tried sudo apt-get install` one some of the dependencies but they only yield similar results. Further `Depends: <something else> but it is not going to be installed` or `but it is not installable`

I'm not yet that familiar with linux, so would appreciate any help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: a couple commands you could try are `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -f install` and then try reinstalling mate. This will clear the local repository, update it, and then try to fix broken dependencies

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks anyway. It's a brand new chromebook so I shouldn't really be having those issues.

Comment: Try installing the files that it said weren't going to be installed (`sudo apt-get install -y mate-desktop-environment-core` and the other three)